# Detect if page is framed and the iframe size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, frame

OK, so here's the problem. I've been hosted igoogle gadgets for a while and deleted them recently. Many sites still embed the codes and there's no way of letting them know to remove them.
My plan is either to redirect all the gadgets (pages) to a 404 and insert a javascript popup there to let the sites framing my pages about the changes - that will be a annoying for them.
Or, to redirect all the pages to another one that will contain a javascript code capable to do all these:
- detect if the page is framed (as far as I know, this is a solution: `if(top.location != self.location)` )
- detect the iframe size (that is the hard part)
- change the content of the page depending on the frame size (some divs hiding and other divs showing will do it)

Again, to avoid confusions: site A displays site B inside an iframe. The javascript must be on site B, basically B must determine if it is framed and take the actions above - detect the frame width/height and display different content for, let's say, 3-4 sizes (example 200px/200px, 300px/300px etc).
I'm not very smart so please, if you have any ideas, share the entire code, not only parts.
Here's a start and my javascript knowledge stops here:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
if(top.location != self.location){
// the magic code that gets the size of the frame that embeds this page and takes the above actions //
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think if your page is inside an iframe then the usual javascript to "get page size" etc. will work based on the iframe sizes.

Comment: Did you try just using window.widht() etc inside the iframe once you've confirmed the page is framed.

Comment: [`frameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frameElement) could be useful, unless [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) is not violated.

Comment: Thanks guys, but can you please share the code? I'm lost here.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... answering my own question :)
I found a jQuery solution:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
if(top.location != self.location){
$(document).ready(function() {
// when to show the 200px div
    if($(window).width() == 200) {
        $('#200').show();
    } else {
        $('#200').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 300px div
    if($(window).width() == 300) {
        $('#300').show();
    } else {
        $('#300').hide();
    }
});
};
</script>
<div id=200>200</div>
<div id=300>300</div>
```